# multi line inputs in ipython

Tags: python, comint, ipython

Say, I typed

```
In [1]: def foo(a, b):
...:     return a+b
...:
```

in the normal, non-emacs ipython shell. Pressing the `up` arrow key afterwards, allows me to get the complete multi-line input back which I then can edit.

```
In [2]: def foo(a, b):
    return a+b_
```

where `_` represents the cursor. Can I replicate this behaviour in Emacs's ipython shell?

Comment: I've done some digging, and I can't find anything suggesting this is possible. You may be stuck with killing and yanking.

Answer (score 4):

I realize it's an old question, but since it was left unanswered, I will bring the fix I found [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9816) after running into the same issue.

1. Make sure your version of IPython is at least 5.4
2. Install [rlipython](https://github.com/ipython/rlipython)  (`sudo pip install rlipython`)
3. Run IPython and then run inside `import rlipython; rlipython.install()`

And that's it.

All the best!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this allows to drop `--simple-prompt` (which is great,t thanks!) but I don't see how it solves the question above?

Comment: What a hidden gem! This solves my problem of using IPython without --simple-prompt in emacs shell. It deserves more upvotes!

Comment: Indeed, tested working for integration of iPython, (Python3.7), Emacs and iSend mode. Without this i could not use IPython with isend-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%cpaste` and `--` to tell ipython to expect multiple lines:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def foo():
:  return 1
:
:--
```

Alternatively, put the code in another buffer and use `python-shell-send-region` or `python-shell-send-defun`.

Comment: I get `UsageError: Line magic function `%cpaste` not found.`