# Emacs IPython prompt symbol is garbled

Tags: character-encoding, ipython

I just installed Fedora 24 with Emacs and IPython. When I launched the IPython shell in Emacs, the prompt symbol, which should be "In [1]", is displayed as "^[[?12l^[[?25h". Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5?newreg=7e15e274404d40d3bf722e1e310ee278

Comment: Which version of IPython are you using? If 5, then yes, it's most likely the same problem.

Comment: Thank you both! I guess I will use Python shell rather than IPython in my Emacs, but I will still use IPython in the Jupyter Notebook. Hope either Emacs or IPython will fix this compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the this post. It took me to an answer which I needed to modify.

**Error** I got was similar garbled (wierd) text when I opened IPYTHON with `C-c C-p` on my simple python file `print("hello World")`.

```
ppppprrrrriiiiinnnnnttttt((((("""""HHHHHeeeeellllllllllooooo     
WWWWWooooorrrrrlllllddddd""""")))))))))))))))
Hello World
```

**Solution** verbatim as per [@ricardoLima's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24572/17941) didn't work for me. I had to re-write it as follows.

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/bin/ipython")
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")
```

**TIP:**

Just use `emacs -q` in the terminal to open a no-init emacs and run these commands with `M-:`. `M-x run-python` and you are good to go.

**P.S.**
Emacs: "This is GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)
of 2019-12-24"
Ubuntu: 16.04
python and Ipython from Anaconda
Python: 3.7.6
IPython:  7.12.0