# How do I filter for IPython prompt characters on Mac OS?

Tags: ipython, comint

I've debugged to this point:

```
OS X El Capitan (10.11.5)
Emacs 24.5.1 with Cocoa (installed from homebrew)
python.el 0.24.5
Python 3.5.1
IPython 5.0.0
```

I've configured IPython to use `NoColor` mode in the default config file.  I start Emacs with this command:

```
open -a /Applications/Emacs.app --args -Q
```

Change the initial buffer to `python-mode` and say `run-python`.  After some boilerplate I get to the prompt I expect:

```
>>>
```

From here I launch IPython with

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()
```

after some more boilerplate I get to this prompt:

```
^[[?12l^[[?25h
```

I *do* have `ansi-color-for-comint-mode` set to `t`.

I don't get this prompt when I launch IPython from Terminal.app, so I'm thinking it's an issue with comint processing some IPython-specific control codes.  But I'm not sure how to dig into that.  Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird shell output when using IPython 5](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5) and/or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24523/emacs-ipython-prompt-symbol-is-garbled?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer, but in general, I tell Python and IPython (which I run directly) to use a simpler prompt. This is part of my `elpy` setup:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "--pylab=qt4 --pdb --nosep --classic"
      python-shell-prompt-regexp ">>> "
      python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "")
```