# python emacs interpreter doesn't pause for input in loops

Tags: shell, ipython

This looks like [Weird shell output when using IPython 5](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5), but it actually is not. I did set

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i --pylab")
```

in .emacs, but I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg
Warning: disable autoreload in ipython_config.py to improve performance.

In [1]: 
In [2]: 
In [3]: 
In [4]: for i in range(3):
File "<ipython-input-4-658181e351fb>", line 1
for i in range(3):
                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

This appears after I hit return. I was expecting the interpreter to wait for the content of the loop. Note that if I do not set the python-shell-interpreter-args, the prompt is garbage, but there is no error.

Comment: Which environment do you use. For me, with python 2.7.9/ipython 2.3.0/Emacs 24.4.1 (and 25.1.1) on recent GNU/linuxen there are no problems with either python nor ipython in both `run-python` (with `C-u M-x run-python` to select python or ipython) and shell mode.

Comment: Try: `for i in arange(3)`

Comment: Hi @pingi, I run GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian; The python, ipython version numbers are in the question above. I tried using C-u M-x run-python, but it generates the same error.

Comment: Hi @Ian, this was a typo in the question, now corrected. The error is the same with range(3) and arange(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was [brought up to the ipython team](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9816). It sounds unlikely that there will be progress from that side.

One option they suggest is reinstalling ipython 4.x (for instance in an Anaconda prompt `pip install --force-reinstall ipython==4.2.1`. If like me, ipython 4.x doesn't work at all, you can reinstall the latest version with `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed ipython`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548957/can-i-force-pip-to-reinstall-the-current-version))

Another option they brought up is [using EIN](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook), which is probably overkill, but it seems to be the best option to me.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with Emacs 25.1.1. Python 3.5.2 and ipython 5 changed things quite a bit and Emacs has not caught up yet. I would file an Emacs bug report.

FYI: 
Use of the pylab import is now discouraged and and the OO interface is recommended for most non-interactive usage

And --pylab now deprecated from notebooks. I would create a jupiter profile and use plt. and np. conventions.

This is what I use:

```
     (setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")
```