# sage-shell-mode repeat the input in the output

Tags: shell, major-mode

I wanted to use sagemath straight in emacs instead of having a terminal open. I tried to use a shell (or eshell for that matters) in emacs and launch sage there, but every time I input a command, the ouput repeats this and then displays the result. Something like:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.1, Release Date: 2017-12-07                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: 2+2
sage: 2+2
4
sage:
```

After a quick search on how to use sage in emacs, I found the neat `sage-shell-mode`. Installed it using `MELPA` (as recommended), but the problem is the same. I have no idea where it comes from and how to fix it.

N.B. when I use emacs shell (or eshell), I have no problem. When I use sage in a terminal, I have no problem. Only when I use sage in emacs (in a shell or using sage-shell-mode) I got the issue.

I'm using Emacs 25.2.2 and SageMath 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of cursor positioning - it looks identical to the problem encountered when running `ipython5` as described here: [Weird shell output when using IPython 5](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5)

Unfortunately, it does not appear that SageMath allows you to pass in the `--simple-prompt` argument.

The SageMath shell does work properly when it can set cursor position, and therefore works well using `M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term`, both of which provide terminal emulation.

Good news for the future: I found a [PR](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/pull/1035) awaiting merge in the [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit) repo that aims to fix this problem.  Then all you will need to do is install from `pip install` or build from source, and set `sage-shell:use-prompt-toolkit` to `t` in the `sage-shell-mode` package.

Comment: `M-x term` is going to do it, even if I lose the possibility to move my cursor freely and copy/paste piece of code to another buffer... I can live like that for now

Comment: Expanded my answer after searching for a better solution - I was going to file an issue, but found that a real solution is already in the pipeline.  Hopefully you will find it `accept`able!

Comment: That's great, I'll definitely look into it and wait for the release!

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer?   Thanks!